# Different breadcrumbs backgrounds depending on page in Joomla

Tags: css, joomla, breadcrumbs

How can I have different breadcrumbs background pictures, depending on visited page? Is this possible without using some additional modules?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you post some code that you have already tried ?

Comment: Find an answer to a similar topic in this link: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5398/adding-custom-css-styling-on-some-of-my-pages

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need a module for this. What you can do is specify a div id on each page (in the content), and then, you will have a CSS that is something like the following:

```
#page-123 .breadcrumb{
    background-color: #ff0000; /* background color is red */
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I feel stupid, because i can't really find where i can set that page id. Could you please tell me where exactly it is?

Comment: just look at the code, every page has it's unique ID

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to modify the index.php file of your template:

Something along the lines:

```
<head>...</head>
<?php 
   $params = &$app->getParams();
   $pageclass = $params->get('page_title');
   $pageclassname = str_replace(' ', '-' ,strtolower($pageclass));
?>
<body id="<?php echo $pageclassname; ?>"> ... </body>
```

That way you have a nice id that you can use for all your styling needs and your css code is more readable.